# How to set second litepicker startDate based on first litepicker startDate selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, date

Hey my fellow Stackoverflowers, I am working with litepicker.js and ran into a snag that I am hoping one of you can help me figure out.

I have built out two separate litepickers and am successfully populating todays date on the first and tomorrows date in the second. (these are also successfully being accepted as the minDate for both)

What I have not been able to figure out is how to set the minDate for the second litepicker to one day after the selected startDate of the first litepicker.

You can see where I am at in this codepen
https://codepen.io/DigitalDesigner/pen/oNGRWzV

HTML Code:

```
<form>
  <input id="start-date" class="form-control start-date"> / 
  <input id="end-date" class="form-control end-date">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
let current = new Date();
let tomorrow = new Date(current.getTime() + 86400000); // + 1 day in ms
tomorrow.toLocaleDateString();
// Add litepicker calendar to stay dates

const startpicker = new Litepicker({
    element: document.getElementById('start-date'),
    singleMode: true,
    allowRepick: true,
    autoRefresh: true,
    format: 'D MMMM YYYY',
    startDate: current,
    minDate: new Date(),
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    numberOfColumns: 1,
    tooltipText: {
        one: 'night',
        other: 'nights'
    },
    tooltipNumber: (totalDays) => {
        return totalDays - 1;
    },
    plugins: ['mobilefriendly']
});
const endpicker = new Litepicker({
    element: document.getElementById('end-date'),
    singleMode: true,
    allowRepick: true,
    autoRefresh: true,
    format: 'D MMMM YYYY',
    startDate: tomorrow,
    minDate: current,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    numberOfColumns: 1,
    tooltipText: {
        one: 'night',
        other: 'nights'
    },
    tooltipNumber: (totalDays) => {
        return totalDays - 1;
    },
});
</script>
```

here is the litepicker site: https://litepicker.com/

How can I set the minDate for the second litepicker based on the first litepickers selected date?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to the code

```
startpicker.on('selected', (date1, date2) => {
    endpicker.setOptions({
        minDate: startpicker.getDate(),
        startDate: startpicker.getDate()
  });
});
```

Comment: this is just another format for setting the current date and tomorrow, what I am needing is to set the second date when the first one is selected to be one day past the selection. I can do it with one litepicker but trying to figure out how to do it when using 2 litepickers one for each date.

Comment: Ok now I understand you, I edited my answer check it

Comment: I tried adding this inside the startpicker litepicker as well as the endpicker as well as outside. my initial dates disappear. do you have a codepen I can look at to see where and how you are implementing this? thanks

Comment: I used the same code you write with the block I wrote, you can find it here https://codepen.io/yazanaldbaisy/pen/jOaEBje
Maybe I didn't get you well, Is this what you need?

Comment: so close, the only thing is when i select the first date the second becomes the same date as opposed to one up. Apparently I missed the last }); when I copied the script. My bad.

Comment: so if start date is changed for example to feb 1st enddate will become feb 2nd. make sense?

Comment: I updated the code in the codepen, check it https://codepen.io/yazanaldbaisy/pen/jOaEBje When you select 28 Jan the end date become 29 Jan

Comment: thats awesome mate. just to verify for my own knowledge 24*60*60*1000 i basically 24hrs in a day x 60 mins in an hr x 60 secs in a min x 1000 ms in a minute? is this more optimal then just adding the 86400000 milliseconds as I did initially for the tomorow variable?

Comment: It's the same, my friend.